# Is absolute value of difference of positive semi-definite matrices a positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two Hermitian positive semi-definite unit trace matrices. Can we say that 
$|A-B|$ is a positive semi-definite matrix?

I think the answer is yes, but I am not sure if it is correct.

This is how I solve it: If $A=UXU'\succeq 0$ and $B=UYU'\succeq 0$, then 
$$C=|UXU'-UYU'|=U|X-Y|U'\succeq 0$$

Comment: What do you mean by $|A|$? Do you simply mean that we take the absolute value of each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
10&3&-2&1\\
3&10&0&9\\
-2&0&10&4\\
1&9&4&10
}
$$
Note that $A$ is positive definite, but $|A|$ is not even positive semidefinite (if you want to verify this, you should use Sylvester's determinant criterion instead of computing eigenvalues).